# How to read the directories' names in / directory Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: directory

when I open `/` directory in Ubuntu 18.10,

some  directories' names are as follows, I am confused how to read them in full.

```
bin = binaries ?
boot = boot
cdrom = -
dev = devices ?
etc = extras ?
home = -
lib = libraries ?
lib64 = libraries 64 bit ?
media = media
mnt = mount
opt = ?
proc = ?
root = -
run = -
sbin = ?
snap = -
srv = ?
sys = system ?
tmp = temporary ?
usr = user ?
var = variable ?
```

[image]

Comment: They are not abbreviations. They are the real names of the directories. You may want to read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). (Note that *folders* are the pretty pictures shown in a GUI; they may correspond to a filesystem *directory* or they may be abstract constructions. The structures in the filesystem are called *directories*.)

Comment: I'm adding this link as I like Ubuntu refs more than wikipedia; it may contain no additional information, but https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview